# Java Web Service with multiple WSDL files

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a set of WSDL files for which I can generate annotated java sources (using Apache CXF wsdl2java). I'm then able to publish a separate Endpoint for each WSDL.

But I need to merge all WSs (all the WSDL definitions) into a single Endpoint with just a different path. Is this possible using basic JAX-WS?

I'm not using any application server. I want to start the WS as a normal Java application.

I understood that it might be possible using the Apache CXF own impementation of the Endpoint. However I'd prefer not using any 3rd party library - if possible.

Thank you.